# Submiting form, it opens the PHP file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, forms

I will be on the point. But anyways, THANKS IN ADVACE.

So basically When I submit the form I made, it submits and stuff, but it redirects the page to the PHP file, and shows this on the browser (not as an alert) :

```
{"status":"success","message":"Yer message was sent."}
```

when the data is successfully validated, and shows this

```
{"status":"fail","message":"Invalid name provided."}
```

when the form doesn't validate. What I want, is that when the form submits, it stays on the same page and if status is true or false, it should alert the message in the array.

I'll write down the scripts and the file names are: index.html, script.js and post.php

## INDEX.HTML

```
<form action='post.php' id='post_message' name='post_message' method="post">
<p>
<input id='email' type="email" class='post' placeholder="Email goes in here.(Required) " class="width" name="email">
<br>
<input id='fname' type="text" class='post' placeholder="First Name (Required) " name="FirstName"><br>
<input id='lname' type="text" class='post' placeholder="Last Name (Required) " name="LastName"><br>
<input id='website' type="url" class='post' placeholder="Website? (Optional!)" class="width" name="website"><br>
<textarea id='message_text' placeholder="Your Message goes here. (Required, DUH!) " name='message'></textarea>
</p>
<button type="submit" class="submit" id='btnPost'></button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="post_message" id="action">
</form>
```

## SCRIPT.JS

```
function clearInputs(){
    $("#fname").val('');
    $("#lname").val('');
    $("#email").val('');
    $("#website").val('');
    $("#message_text").val('');
}

$('#btnPost').click(function() {

    var data = $("#post_message").children().serializeArray();

    $.post($("#post_message").attr('action'), data, function(json){

        if (json.status == "fail") {
            alert(json.message);
        }
        if (json.status == "success") {
            alert(json.message);
            clearInputs();
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

## POST.PHP

```
<?php
if($_POST){ 
    if ($_POST['action'] == 'post_message') {
    $fname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['FirstName']);
    $lname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['LastName']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $website = htmlspecialchars($_POST['website']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
    $date = date('F j, Y, g:i a');
    if(preg_match('/[^\w\s]/i', $fname) || preg_match('/[^\w\s]/i', $lname)) {
        fail('Invalid name provided.');
    }
    if( empty($fname) || empty($lname) ) {
        fail('Please enter a first and last name.');
    }
    if( empty($message) ) {
        fail('Please select a message.');
    }
    if( empty($email)) {
        fail('Please enter an email');
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO portmessage SET first_name='$fname', last_name='$lname', email = '$email', website = '$website', message = '$message', date = '$date'";
    $result = db_connection($query);

    if ($result) {
        $msg = "Yer message was sent.";
        success($msg);
    } else {
        fail('Message failed, Please try again.');
    }
    exit;
}
}
function db_connection($query) {
    mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', '######', '####')
        OR die(fail('Could not connect to database.'));
    mysql_select_db('####');

    return mysql_query($query);
}

function fail($message) {
    die(json_encode(array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => $message)));
}
function success($message) {
    die(json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message)));
}
```

?>

And yes, it DOES submit the form to the database, but I can't overcome the alert and redirecting problem.
Thanks, again!

Comment: Sorry, @hindmost, I did use Ajax. Please see the edit. It submitted the question halfway when I was writing it. My bad.

Comment: You have to prevent the form submission inside button's `onclick` handler by calling `preventDefault` or by returning `false`.

Comment: Doesn't work. returning false doesn't submit the form..

Comment: This is exactly what you need to do (don't submit the form) since now you do two post requests: 1) ajax post; 2) default submission according to form's `action` attribute. And this is your problem

Comment: Uhh, Can you make an answer for this? I don't get it... returning false doesn't submit the form, neither does it submit the data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your form client side(using javascript)

**HTML**

```
<form action='post.php' id='post_message' name='post_message' method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form();">
```

**Javascript**

```
function validate_form()
{
     var success = true;
     if($("[name=FirstName]").val() == "")
     {
         success = false;
     }
     // your test case goes here
     // you can alert here if you find any error
     return success;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what about invalid characters? (The preg match thing); and even success is false the PHP script WILL continue. I want to learn the PHP way.

Comment: You can test all validation in validate_from() function. If any input violate validation case then just return false form will not submit.